# What did Garrett mean when asking about Robbi's Jack's being a club?

Tags: texas-hold-em, poker-theory, poker-strategy, cheating

Re [Garrett Adelstein and Robbi Jade Lew](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/11902/if-robbi-jade-lew-is-cheating-how), Robbi says in this part 7:07 here [Robbi hero calls Garrett with jack high on hustler casino live | weirdest poker hand](https://youtu.be/lXoWZE90n28?t=427)

> If my Jack wasn't a club, I would've been out.

and then Garrett asks

> 'What do you mean "if your Jack wasn't a club" ?'

Well I figure it means that since the flop had 2 clubs, like that was a big reason why Robbi didn't fold after the flop. Like 9-10-J all clubs that's like close to a straight and a flush. Soooo....ugh...?

I'll agree that the all-in on the turn is extremely strange (not really into poker but whatever fine if people say so, yeah I guess I wouldn't do that unless I knew my opponent were bluffing), but I think the flop, much like [chess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carlsen%E2%80%93Niemann_controversy) and probably poker, [speaks for itself](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/40576/if-hans-niemann-is-cheating-how).

**Guess:**

Oh wait Garrett is asking about the not folding or at least not going all in after the *turn* rather than after the *flop*?

Comment: The term you want to look up is "blockers", since having a card in your hand means it's out of the deck and not in your opponents' hand. With a preflop raise, flop bet and turn bet-allin, the patterns that Garret could have would presumably be very limited in the high range, and semibluffs playing to represent a clubs flush straight draw of QJs, J8s, J7s would not exist. However, the blockers here might actually make it better to fold NOT call, and you might also just forget all of that, because this has been a very sketchy situation https://twitter.com/HCLPokerShow/status/1576072826137649152

Comment: @Unihedron thanks. post as answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The term you want to look up is "blockers", since having a card in your hand means it's out of the deck and not in your opponents' hand. With a preflop raise, flop bet and turn bet-allin, the patterns that Garret could have would presumably be very limited in the high range, and semibluffs playing to represent a clubs flush straight draw of QJs, J8s, J7s would not exist. However, the blockers here might actually make it better to fold NOT call, and you might also just forget all of that, because this has been a very sketchy situation twitter.com/HCLPokerShow/status/1576072826137649152 – Unihedron